# authenticating in parent domain by using child domain user?

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-xp, system-administration

I created a child domain and trying to **login on parent domain with a user of child domain**.

I am doing login attempt on Windows Login Dialog at PDC of parent domain.

Login is failing as parent domain could not authenticate user of child domain.

**Is it possible to login in this way?** If yes, the how can i achive it?

Notes:-

Both are Windows 2003 domains.
child domain is direct child of parent domain.
There is 2-way transitive trust between child and parent (created automatically).

Comment: Seems like this is for serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can logon a parent domain using a child domain user.

Domain controller is kind of special.  Unlike a regular member server, normal user cannot logon to the domain controller by default.

You need to setup the group policy to enable that.  [This MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785165%28WS.10%29.aspx) explains how to do that.  Basically, you need to go to `Default Domain Controller Security Policy` and under the `User Rights Assignment`, add the AD user or AD group to `Allow log on locally` settings.